# TFS: Moving a Team Project from one server to another?

Tags: tfs, administration

is there a (simple) way to move a single TeamProject from one server to another? Including source code, work items, documents, project site...

We don't want to move our server from one machine to another. Just a single project from server A to server B.

Answer (score 17):

You have two options

1. You can use the TFS to TFS migration tool: [Click Here](http://tfstotfsmigration.codeplex.com/).  This doesn't include the WSS project site.
2. Or you can backup your TFS db and restore on a new TFS instance, then use the [TFSDeleteProject.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482.aspx) to remove the projects you don't want.

The latter option is the easiest, but will not merge the backed up projects with any existing projects on the target instance.  Existing projects will be lost.  WSS sites can also be moved in this manner as well.  See [How to: Back Up a Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070.aspx)

Comment: For what it is worth, this will hopefully get easier in TFS2010 - but this is a great answer for what is needed today.  It's just anything but "simple" :-)

Answer (score 7):

The TFS to TFS migration tool is obsolete. The features you are looking for is part of TFS Integration Platform.

Goto http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/ for more info.

Comment: Even this is obsolete now -- "TFS Integration Platform will not be supported past May 31, 2016."

Answer (score 5):

In TFS 2010 you can detach the Project Collection database using the TFS Admin Console and then re-attach it to another TFS Server.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want an entire Project Collection to be moved from one TFS server to another:

1) Detach the collection via Admin Console.

2) Backup the Tfs_SomethingCollection database using SSMS, then restore it to the other database server.

3) On the second TFS Admin Console, attach the project collection.  It will show up as an available collection to attach just because it has been restored in the second sql server instance.

I did not migrate the Tfs_Configuration database.  In my case I was not utilizing reporting services, build services, or sharepoint.

I hadn't installed the second TFS server and was wondering, what options to choose when installing, and if you should install it after or before restoring the migrated DB(it doesn't really matter):  Install TFS on the second machine.  If TFS and its database instance will be on seperate servers, then choose Advanced configuration and specify the name of the DB server instance.  When you have an opportunity to create a DefaultCollection, then opt to skip that step.  The install will create a new Tfs_Configuration DB on the new server.  Then follow the above steps to migrate the collection DB to the new DB server instance and attach it.

Programmers will need to add the new server to Team Explorer, and hit Change Source Control... twice in a row for each solution.  Make sure the local path mappings are correct, and then Bind each solution/project.