# TFS: Moving from one server to another

Tags: tfs

How do I move my code and change history from one TFS server to another?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677608/tfs-moving-a-team-project-from-one-server-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a "[TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/)" project on CodePlex which you can use.  It makes migrating very easy and can keep your history.

Answer (score 7):

Use this: **[TFS to TFS Migration Tool](http://www.codeplex.com/tfstotfsmigration)** from CodePlex