# Team Foundation Server 2013: Shifting Code Base From One Server To Another Server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to shift the code base from one server to another without losing tracking history and binding to the work-items?

Comment: "Migrating" is a better term than "shifting". You will need to update your bindings though, as a binding is "server path + local path".

Comment: possible duplicate of [TFS: Moving a Team Project from one server to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677608/tfs-moving-a-team-project-from-one-server-to-another)

Comment: depends on what you want, are you talking about migrating a team project collection? If so, just backup-detach-attach. If not, it can get complicated.